# How can i create a new element and add onclick attribute to it using dom Manipulation in react

Tags: reactjs

> this code works fine in JavaScript but fails to call AddTextBtn function in React.What did i miss?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

class onClickTest extends Component {

```
AddBtn=()=>{
    let btn=document.createElement("button");
    let container=document.getElementById("container");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("addTextBtn"));
    btn.setAttribute("onClick","{this.addTextBtn}");
    container.appendChild(btn);
}

addTextBtn=()=>{
    let p=document.createElement("p");
    let container=document.getElementById("container");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("done"));
    container.appendChild(p);

}
render(){
  return (
    <div id="container">
        <button id="AddButton" onClick={this.AddBtn}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

export default onClickTest;

Answer (score 0):

React has its own way of manipulating the DOM so you should never manipulate it yourself.
What you could do is this:

```
class MyComponent extends Compnent {
  state = {
    showText: false,
    pElements: []
  };
  
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ showText: true });
  }

  hanldeNewP() {
    this.setState({ pElements: [...this.state.pElements, <p>Done</p>] });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div id="container">
          <button
            id="AddButton"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Add
          </button>
          { this.state.showText &&
             <button onClick={this.handleNewP}>Add P tag</button>
          }

          { this.state.pElements }
      </div>
    );
 }
```

The second button will only be visible if showText is true which happens when the
first button is clicked. Then whenever the second button is clicked a new p element is added in the pElements array which are then rendered using this line: { this.state.pElements }

And if you prefer functional components:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
  const [pElements, setPElements] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowText(true);
  };

  const handleNewP = () => {
    setPElements([...pElements, <p>Done</p>]);
  }

  return (
    <div id="container">
        <button
          id="AddButton"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Add
        </button>
        { showText &&
           <button onClick={handleNewP}>Add P tag</button>
        }

        { pElements }
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help.. but this button just displays p tag.what i wanted is to create a new button and the second button should create a  p tag every time i click . can u help me solving this problem?